# Trigger By option in Power Bi refresh?

Tags: powerbi

Is there a way, We can set Trigger by functionality in powerbi?

for example once ETL load completes it should trigger power bi refresh automatically. If ETL load fails power bi refresh has to wait until it completes.

Thanks,
Bhanu

Comment: AFAIK, the short answer is no. Scheduled refresh on the powerbi service can only be set on the hour and half hour

Comment: How you do ETL? Can you execute a PowerShell script for example, when it completes? In this case you can use [Refresh Dataset In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/refreshdatasetingroup) REST API.

Comment: @Rudy Currently there is no setting from power bi side to dynamically control the refresh, Agreed with Andrey Nikolov to setup something using powershell or your choice to invoke REST API.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov Thanks for the reply

Comment: @Mboolean- Thanks for reply, Can you please provide any step by step documentation.

Comment: @macaw_9227 Thanks for reply